# maximum from user input + string

Tags: java

I have a home work that requires user to input the name and process of products using for loop and print the price and name of the most expensive product. I have already figure out using the loop and transferring the variables to the constructor.

```
int numberOfProducts; //user input

for (i=0; i<=numberOfProducts; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Name of product" + i);
    System.out.println("price of product" +i);

    Product myProduct= new Product (name, price);
    //enter code here

}
```

I know I can write something like:

```
If max<price
    price=max;
```

to find the max, but, have no idea how to incorporate the name when I print the maximum price.

Could you please give me a hint???

Thanks!

Comment: So are you trying to find the product with the highest price, each time you add a new item?

Comment: Please post your attempts and the exact problem you are having...

Comment: Yes, the loop I wrote above will take the price and product name from lets say, 4 items. I can find the maximum by: if max<productPrice, productPrice=max. But how do I make the program know the name of the highest price? Ideas will be fine, not asking for codes.

Comment: well in that case you need to keep track of a "max" product. By default make the very first entry this "max" product, THEN each time you add a new item, just compare the price of each item. `if max.getPrice < this.getPrice` then set the new Product as the "max" product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to keep both the maximum price and the name of the product with that maximum price. For example,

```
Product[] products = // your products.
Product mostExpensiveProduct = product[0];

for (Product product : products) {
  if (product.getPrice() > mostExpensiveProduct.getPrice()) {
    mostExpensiveProduct = product;
  }
}

System.out.println("Most expensive product is " + mostExpensiveProduct.getName() + " with price " + mostExpensiveProduct.getPrice());
```